# Universal Analytics Java API zero results but API explorer has results with the same parameters

Tags: java, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Universal Analytics Java API returning zero results but API explorer returned values with the same dimensions and metrics.

I used the ff. dimensions:
ga:date, ga:pagePath, ga:pagePathLevel1, ga:pagePathLevel2, ga:pagePathLevel3, ga:hostname, ga:pageTitle

and the ff. metrics:
ga:pageviews, ga:timeOnPage, ga:exits

On Java API, I tried a couple of combinations with the dimensions and it seems that ga:pagePath, ga:pagePathLevel1, ga:pagePathLevel2, ga:pagePathLevel3 doesn't go well with ga:hostname, ga:pageTitle

However, I get results with using all the dimensions above using the API explorer